# Is there any way to make SharePoint custom client side web parts responsive

Tags: sharepoint

I'm developing SharePoint Intranet portal and the need is to develop custom web parts ,the problem is the web parts are not responsive,so is there any way to make web parts responsive?

Comment: Use bootsrap library to make your UI responsive or  your material design your UI.. Sharepoint Framework has nothing to do with responsiveness..

Comment: My UI is already responsive The web part is placed inside iframe so it automatically fixes height and width.

Comment: umm in that case use `media queries` and make your design responsive for that specific width or height.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of responsive design to make suit for your reference:

[image]

[SharePoint grid and responsive design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/design/grid-and-responsive-design)